# Angular form.io removeRow

Tags: angularjs, api

I'm working with Angular and the form.io API, and have an add row button that can be directly clicked inserting a blank row, or a number of pre selected values can be clicked which will trigger this add row click event, and then populate the input. This all works well, the problem I can't seem to solve is that the remove row buttons works as expected in the case that the button is manually clicked, but if it is triggered via the pre selected value buttons the remove row button will remove the last row not the selected row. There are allot of moving pieces so please ask if additional code would be useful:

//Form.IO relevant code:

```
app.controller('formioDataGrid', [
'$scope',
function($scope) {
  // Ensure each data grid has a valid data model.
  $scope.data = $scope.data || {};
  $scope.data[$scope.component.key] = $scope.data[$scope.component.key] || [{}];

  // Pull out the rows and cols for easy iteration.
  $scope.rows = $scope.data[$scope.component.key];
  $scope.cols = $scope.component.components;

  // Add a row the to grid.
  $scope.addRow = function() {
    if (!Array.isArray($scope.rows)) {
      $scope.rows = [];
    }
    $scope.rows.push({});
  };

  // Remove a row from the grid.
  $scope.removeRow = function(index) {
    $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
  };
}
]);
```

My pre selected values button click code to, when clicked, trigger the add row button and then populate the row:

```
var element1 = angular.element('a[ng-click="addRow()"]');
element1.click();
$('.myTable ng-form input:last').prop('value', $(this).text());
```

Code on each remove button

```
<tr class="formio-data-grid-row ng-scope" ng-repeat="rowData in data[component.key] track by $index">
<td class="ng-scope" ng-init="component.hideLabel = true" ng-repeat="component in component.components track by $index">
<td>
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeRow($index)">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I've tried a dozen ways of "simulating" a button click, but I think I am missing something here. Any ideas how to call addRow, populate the value and maintain the correct remove row functionality?

Comment: why not just calling `$scope.addRow();` directly from the controller?

Comment: Glad to help. Best of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue, as I understand it, these calls I used to set the value:

```
var element1 = angular.element('a[ng-click="addRow()"]');
element1.click();
$('.myTable ng-form input:last').prop('value', $(this).text());
```

Need to be accompanied by the following to ensure angular properly updates the scope:

```
$('.myTable ng-form input:last').trigger('input');
```

After adding this line the remove buttons worked consistently.